# My CPU supports "turbo" clock boosting, but CPUPower says it doesn't; who's right?

Tags: cpu, amd, cpu-frequency, boost, turbo-core

I recently bought a new CPU (AMD Ryzen 3 2200G) which supports a "Boost Clock", however when I run `cpupower frequency-info` I get:

```
boost state support:
  Supported: no
  Active: no
  Boost States: 0
  Total States: 3
  Pstate-P0:  3500MHz
  Pstate-P1:  2300MHz
  Pstate-P2:  1600MHz
```

`turbostat` says that `cpufreq boost: 1`.

According to AMD:

> Max boost for AMD processors is the maximum frequency achievable by a single core on the processor running a bursty single-threaded workload. Max boost will vary based on several factors, including, but not limited to: thermal paste; system cooling; motherboard design and BIOS; the latest AMD chipset driver; and the latest OS updates. GD-150.

I'm using the stock AMD Wraith Cooler with pre-applied thermal paste. I've updated the BIOS on my motherboard (Asus Prime A320I-K/CSM), reset the settings a few times, and made sure that the boost clock option was set to "Auto" instead of "Disabled".

In other questions regarding clock boosting not working, CPUPower always says that it's "Supported" even if it's not "Active". With all this in mind, I don't know whether CPUPower should be reporting that "boost state" is supported. Given that this is a new CPU, I'm worried that it's defective in some way that is preventing clock boosting from working properly.

**Should CPUPower be reporting that "boost state" is "Supported", even if that functionality is disabled for other reasons? Are there any settings or parameters that I missed that might be disabling this functionality? Could this discrepancy be a sign that the CPU or some other component in my system is defective? If so, which components would be most likely?**

Raw output of `cpumode` (requested script):

```
Boost: on   
schedutil mode is currently activated.
1431MHz
1419MHz
1419MHz
1419MHz
No frequency limit is enforced.
```

Raw output of `cpupower frequency-info`:

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 1.60 GHz - 3.50 GHz
  available frequency steps:  3.50 GHz, 2.30 GHz, 1.60 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: userspace powersave ondemand conservative performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.60 GHz and 3.50 GHz.
              The governor "schedutil" may decide which speed to use
              within this range.
  current CPU frequency: 1.60 GHz (asserted by call to hardware)
  boost state support:
    Supported: no
    Active: no
    Boost States: 0
    Total States: 3
    Pstate-P0:  3500MHz
    Pstate-P1:  2300MHz
    Pstate-P2:  1600MHz
```

Comment: According to my script output, boost is enabled and working. Maybe `cpupower` doesn't fully support/recognize your CPU. Run any single threaded app which uses 100% of CPU, e.g. `7z b -mmt1` and check that you see frequencies above 3.5GHz, e.g. `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov It works! Thank you. I've been trying different CPU performance scaling governors and it seems that the "performance" one doesn't work properly on my machine, either; perhaps this bug is more serious than just the Userspace utility? Also on heavier loads, all cores go to the boost clock speed, which I didn't know was possible.